# Is There a way to use Document.getTime() From a Certain Time?

Tags: javascript, date

By default `document.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, but if I want it from a different date do I have to use addition/subtraction to do so, or can I just pass some sort of parameter that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: you can create a new Date and pass in the parameters there

Comment: `document.getTime === undefined`

Comment: [Here are the MDN docs for the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  Also, [please search before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without subtraction, but this works:

```
var d=new Date("November 25, 2014 02:01:00");
var n=new Date("November 25, 2014 02:00:00");
var x = d.getTime() - n.getTime();
document.write(x + " milliseconds since "+n);
```

Please note, document.write shouldn't be used in production

If you want a time from now to anytime in the past, this will do it:

```
var d=new Date();
var n=new Date("November 25, 2014 02:00:00");
var x = d.getTime() - n.getTime();
document.write(x + " milliseconds since "+n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a time from lets say December 25 2013

```
var date = new Date("December 25, 2013 00:00:00");
document.write( dt.getTime() );
```

Comment: Can you explain this please? When I put var date = new Date("November 25, 2013 00:00:00"); I get 1385334000000 // and when I put var date = new Date("November 25, 2014 00:00:00"); I get 1416870000000 // how can the second one (1 year after, way less difference, be a higher number?

Comment: This code returns the number of milliseconds between Midnight Jan 1st 1970 UTC and Midnight December 25th 2013 *local time*.  Doesn't sound like what the OP wants.  (Then again, it's pretty hard to tell what the OP wants here.)

Comment: Basically, I just have a program where you enter a date into an input field and it tells you the second since that date.

Comment: @KareemKamel oh wow it was very confusing what you wanted. My mistake